# How to use Firebase console with a database created using GCP console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

After creating a Firestore database using GCP console (Google Cloud Platform console) and adding some data there, I don't see my project/database appear in Firebase console.

I just get a screen that prompts to create a new project.

It is required to use Firebase console for certain operations such as editing the security rules.

Answer (score 1):

In Firebase console, click on Create new Project. Under the field for project name, there should be a dropdown menu showing projects created in GCP. Select the project you want and it will add this project to Firebase console without requiring you to create a new project.

The data you already have will still be there and will become accessible from Firebase console.